# when curl_multi_wait return if data are not available?

Tags: c++, curl

Hello I am confused with the curl_multi_wait description
Specifically with the following paragraph
*If no extra file descriptors are provided and libcurl has no file descriptor to offer to wait for, this function will return immediately. (Try curl_multi_poll instead if you rather avoid this behavior.)*

The above paragraph means that when extra_fds are null the curl_multi_wait will return immediately?

For example let's assume that the following call take place

```
curl_multi_wait(curlm, NULL, 0, 500, &numfds);
```

This will return immediately or waiting to get data until reaches the 500 msec threshold?

Is it needed any flag to make curl_multi_wait blocking?

Comment: Is this the documentation you were following? https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_wait.html

Comment: @darclander, yes this the documentation